# How does TFS determine what directory to use for the output from a build?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I'm setting up some TFS build definitions.  I see that once I run a build, the work is done within a subfolder of a subdirectory of /Agent/_work.  It appears that the subfolder is the same between different executions of the same build definition, but I see no way to know in advance where I should expect TFS to set its working directory, nor do I see any way of specifying the name of the directory manually.

How does TFS determine what directory to use for the output from a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation on [build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables). The base folder can be accessed via the `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` variable. The source folder is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

You can't set this. It's determined by the agent's configuration.

Comment: Is this variable determined each time the build commences?  I don't want to set this variable.  I just want to know how I can find out what its value is.

Comment: The folder is determined by the agent on a build by build basis. You should reference the appropriate build variable in your build definitions.